# How could I create a new struct from an unpredictable db.Query()?

Tags: postgresql, go, struct

I'm using `SELECT *` in a `db.query()` to return columns from a table. Typically, I would `fmt.Scan()` the rows into a pre-declared `struct{}` for further manipulation, but in this case, the table columns change frequently so I'm not able to use a declared `struct{}` as part of my `Scan()`.

I've been struggling to figure out how I might dynamically build a `struct{}` based on the column results of the `db.query()` which I could subsequently call on the use of for `Scan()`. I've read a little about `reflect` but I'm struggling to determine if this is right for my use-case or if I might have to think about something else.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use a `map[string]interface{}`, and then get the column values from that map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get column names from resulting rowset and prepare a slice for the scan.

Example (https://go.dev/play/p/ilYmEIWBG5S) :

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock"
)

func main() {
    // mock db
    db, mock, err := sqlmock.New()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    columns := []string{"id", "status"}

    mock.ExpectQuery("SELECT \\* FROM table").
        WillReturnRows(sqlmock.NewRows(columns).AddRow(1, "ok"))

    // actual code
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM table")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    cols, err := rows.Columns()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    data := make([]interface{}, len(cols))
    strs := make([]sql.NullString, len(cols))
    for i := range data {
        data[i] = &strs[i]
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        if err := rows.Scan(data...); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        for i, d := range data {
            fmt.Printf("%s = %+v\n", cols[i], d)
        }
    }
}
```

This example reads all columns into strings. To detect column type one can use `rows.ColumnTypes` method.

Comment: Thank you serge-v. This was the pointer I needed to get to where I needed to be.